# Case statement in sql

Tags: sql, loops, if-statement, case

I want to create a computed column in SAS enterprise guide where it’ll show car items if it meets certain conditions.

- There are 75 car items (T.TS_Items) such as windscreen, tyres, steering wheel etc.
- Each item has a unique ID (T.TS_NUM) so T.TS_NUM =1 to T.TS_NUM =75.

And I want to then give each new car item a label such as labelNo_01 to labelNo_75.

So, if the vehicle type is Honda (T.TS_F_NUM = 2), type is hatchback(T.TS_TYPE = I) and T.TS_NUM =1 then the new column name is LabelName_01 with a item such as windscreen.

and if the vehicle type changes for example - the vehicle type is Toyota (T.TS_F_NUM = 1) 
but the rest is the same it will give me the 75 car item for Toyota.

My code:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MotorVehicle AS 
SELECT 
T.TS_VEHICLE_RDES, 
/* FI_Label_01 */
Case When 
T.TS_F_NUM in (1,2) And  
T.TS_TYPE = I And 
T.TS_NUM =1 Then T.T_Item
else T.T_Item
End
AS FI_Label_01
FROM T.T_ITEM 
WHERE  T.TS_F_NUM = 41 
ORDER BY T.TS_NUM ;
QUIT;
```

The above is simple and works but I am not sure how to add an Else or Else if statement. Basically when I use the above code and hard code the vehicle type to 1 (toyota) in the where statement its working and its gives me only Toyota but its also giving me all the types instead of just hatchback. I want to add a condition where its only giving the type hatchback but I dont know how or where in the above code it’ll go in.

Also a **loop** would help so I dont have to repeat the process for each vehicle type. Hope this information helps.

Some Data.

```
T.TS_F_NUM      T.TS_TYPE       T.T_Item           T.TS_NUM
1               I               windscreen        1
2               I               side mirror       2
1               C               Side mirror       3
2               C               passenger door    4
1               I               dashboard         5
2               I               gear box          6
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample data for the same? I guess we can decode but need to check with sample data

Comment: +1 Ajith Wish he could just append his question with table schema and sample data.

Comment: @AjithSasidharan I have added some data at the end. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you're pretty close, I've got some similar code and mine looks like this and works :)
This obviously has sub sub rules but all the principles are the same for ELSE, I don't think there is an ELSE IF...

```
CASE WHEN
    RULE_1 = TRUE THEN 
        CASE WHEN RULE_2 = TRUE AND RULE_3 = TRUE THEN
            CASE WHEN 
                RULE_4 = TRUE
            THEN 
                ITEM_1
            ELSE 
                ITEM_2
            END
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN RULE_5 THEN
                ITEM_3
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN RULE_6 = TRUE THEN 
                    ITEM_4
                ELSE
                    ITEM_5
                END
            END 
        END
END
```

Comment: I have tried to add the conditions in a differently but I am not getting it quite right. its almost there but not quote there.

Comment: @Beanie why don't you update the question with what you have tried so far, may be it will help us to help you out further :)

Comment: @bonCodigo, I have added the code that is working but also gives me all types. hope this helps